# $form table displays no table data

Tags: forms

I just made a $form['table']. It shows enough rows (the count of the total rows in database) only it doesn't show the results. I tried using #value, #title, #markup but nothing works

Screenshot of result:

[image: result]

My code:

```
function push_notifications_stats_form($form, &$form_state) {
$form = array();
$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = db_query('SELECT * FROM push_notifications_messages WHERE msg_appID = :app_id', array(':app_id' => $id));
$qCount = db_query('SELECT * FROM push_notifications_messages WHERE msg_appID = :app_id', array(':app_id' => $id))->rowCount();

$form['table'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => array(t('Message'), t('Device'), t('Date')),
    '#rows' => array(),
    );

foreach($query as $result) {
  for($i = 1; $i <= $qCount; $i++) {
    $form['table']["#rows"]["r$i"] = array(
        "'c1'" => array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#value' => t('hoi'),
          ),
        'c2' => array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('device')
          ),
        'c3' => array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('device'),
          ),      
      );
  }
}


$form['id'] = array(
'#type' => 'item',
'#title' => 'Application ID',
'#description' => t('The application ID you are viewing: @appId', array('@appId' => $id)),
);  

return $form;

}
```

When I check the $form with dsm it does show the results.. And also when I use my browsers element inspector it does show the values. Only it puts them inside the first  tag. while it should be between the  tags

```
<td #type="textfield" #value="hoi" #data="hoi"></td>
```

Comment: Perhaps this similar question will help: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/116534/23853

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mis-using `#header` and `#rows` properties of the [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#header_prop) and getting them confused for variables passed to the [theme_table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) function that is being called with the `form['#theme'] => 'table'`.

This question is similar and might be what you're looking for: [How to insert a theme table form inside an existing form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37007/how-to-insert-a-theme-table-form-inside-an-existing-form/116534#116534)

Perhaps you want to use the [tableselect](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#tableselect) element?